# What is geometric engineering in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Could someone help me to understand what geometric engineering in quantum field theory is? I didn't find any introductary articles online. Thank you!

Edit : Here is my background. I am math major. I know representation theory of quantum groups, quiver moduli space and hall algebra and some of algebraic geometry. I know very little physics except some brief mention from articles. That's why I feel difficult to follow the original paper posted on arxiv.  What I want to know basicly is 1) what they want to do 2)what they did 3)what part of math they used.

Ps: Thank Urs for your suggestions.

Comment: It's hard to answer a question like this if you don't share where you came upon the term. For instance, I find http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9609239 and http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9611090 where the term was apparently introduced, but then I have to guess that (1) this is the same usage that you are trying to understand and (2) for some reason you do not find them introductory enough? Please fill out some more details in your question, including your background and what you find confusing, see  http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/882/how-to-write-a-good-mathoverflow-question

Comment: A good resource for constructing MO questions is meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/70.

Comment: I'd think the question is clear enough. Anyone who ever tried to extract a mathematical story from leafing through string theory articles scattered on the arXiv knows this question: "Is there any document that tries to actually explain this, in the usual manner that a mathematician might recognize as an explanation?" For some topics in string theory this exists. For geometric engineering as a whole maybe not so much. But look for articles by Balázs Szendrői, see   http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+engineering